Deserialize struct containing tag and vector of enums with serde
I have a setup like this
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct GameData {
    game: String,
    player_data: Vec<MarioPartyData>,
    <more common data>
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum MarioPartyData {
    MarioParty(MarioParty),
    MarioParty2(MarioParty2),
    MarioParty3(MarioParty3),
    <many more variants>
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MarioParty {
    stars: i32,
    coins: i32,
    spaces_walked: i32
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MarioParty2 {
    stars: i32,
    coins: i32
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MarioParty3 {
    stars: i32,
    coins: i32
}

This almost works. The problem is that some games have the exact same structure so when I deserialize MarioParty3, in this instance, it becomes a MarioParty2 variant, because that's the first one it matches. The game field should be able to uniquely identify which game to deserialize into, but I can't figure out how to use the different tagging macros in serde to accomplish that, or if it's even possible. I'm hoping to avoid implementing the deserializer myself. There's also a slight wrinkle in that the game field won't be "MarioParty3", but rather "Mario Party 3", I think this might be handled with something like #[serde(rename = "Mario Party 3")] though?
A valid JSON input for a MarioParty3 instance might look like this
{
  "game": "Mario Party 3",
  "player_data": [
    {
      "stars": 3,
      "coins" 45
    }
  ]
}

I'm not against changing any of the structures I have in rust, but the JSON coming in is pretty firm. Any advice is appreciated!

The most straightforward way to represent this JSON using Serde is with an adjacently tagged enum.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct GameData {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    player_data: MarioPartyData,
    // <more common data>
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "game", content = "player_data")]
enum MarioPartyData {
    #[serde(rename = "Mario Party")]
    MarioParty(Vec<MarioParty>),
    #[serde(rename = "Mario Party 2")]
    MarioParty2(Vec<MarioParty2>),
    #[serde(rename = "Mario Party 3")]
    MarioParty3(Vec<MarioParty3>),
    // <many more variants>
}

This does change the structure so that the Vec occurs inside the enum, forcing each Vec to only contain one type. This sounds like it reflects your JSON alright, but might change how you deal with it in Rust.

Ah! I didn't consider moving the Vec inside the enum. That seems to work! And it actually represents the data better, every instance in the Vec should be of the same variant. For posterity, it wasn't obvious to me that I needed to remove the game field from GameData for this solution to work, but after doing that it's great! Thanks!
